# Bootstrap 3 + Less - disable collapse-navbar at bigger screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

What I'm trying to get is a navbar that is collapsed at small screens but  not at bigger ones.
At the moment it is collapsed at any size.
So how can I manage to disable collapsing at bigger screens.
My HTML:

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="row">
  <div id="nav-toggle" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <p>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="fa fa-bars">Menü</span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
    <div id="navbar-collapseY" class="navbar collapse collapse-navbar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home active"><span class="sr-only">Home</span></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        ...
        <li>
          <a href="kontakt.html">
            Kontakt
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```css
#nav-toggle p {
  a {
    color: white;
  }
  font-size:@font-size-base * 1.15;
  text-align:center;
}
.nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.nav-pills:hover,
.nav-justified:hover,
.nav-pills:focus,
.nav-justified:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

THX for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Navbar</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what u want..